# Label position not returning correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I am trying to determine a label's position so as to place other labels below.

When I try to output the data on a specific label I get `0.000` as a output on log.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
    ...
    postTextLabel.text  = postText;
    postTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(postTextLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                     postThumbView.frame.origin.y + postThumbView.frame.size.height,
                                     postTextLabel.frame.size.width,
                                     postTextLabel.frame.size.height);
    [postTextLabel resizeToFit];

    postAuthorNameLabel.text = postAuthorName;
    postTimestampLabel.text  = postTimestamp;

    NSLog(@"%f", postTimestampLabel.frame.origin.y);
```

Comment: Where do you set it's frame?

Comment: @Brett - `postTimestampLabel` is set in IB and wired to an IBOutlet

Comment: And what is the value of the frame in IB?

Comment: not sure I understand but `x, y, w, h` are `58, 24, 247, 16`

Comment: Can't really help without seeing more code. Things to look for: How are you synthesising your properties? In which method are these frames being set? Is there anywhere else you are setting the postTimestampLabel frame?

Comment: What is resizeToFit, show us the code?

Comment: Where are you using that code? In a UIViewController? In what method of it's life cycle?

Comment: Did you mean to use [postTextLabel sizeToFit]?